# memory calculation is going negative while using malloc_hook

Tags: unix, memory, malloc, gnu

I want to track memory usage through the the program execution. I have used malloc_hook to capture all the memory related calls. below is the program

```
long int memory_bytes_hook = 0;
long int peak_memory_hook = 0;
std::mutex memory_mutex_hook;
static void my_init_hook (void);
static void *my_malloc_hook (size_t, const void *);
static void my_free_hook (void*, const void *);
static void* my_realloc_hook (void *ptr, size_t size, const void *caller);
static void *(*old_malloc_hook)(size_t, const void *);
static void (*old_free_hook)(void*, const void *);
static void *(*old_realloc_hook)(void *ptr, size_t size, const void *caller);


static void
my_init_hook (void)
{
  __malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;
  __free_hook = my_free_hook;
  __realloc_hook = my_realloc_hook ;
}

static  void *
my_malloc_hook (size_t size, const void *caller)
{
  const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(memory_mutex_hook);
  void *result;

  __malloc_hook = nullptr;
  __free_hook = nullptr ;
  __realloc_hook = nullptr ;
  result = malloc (size);
  memory_bytes_hook += malloc_usable_size(result);
  if(peak_memory_hook  < memory_bytes_hook )
    peak_memory_hook = memory_bytes_hook ;
  my_init_hook();
  return result;
}

static void* my_realloc_hook (void *ptr, size_t size, const void *caller)
{
   const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(memory_mutex_hook);
   __malloc_hook = nullptr;
   __free_hook = nullptr;//old_free_hook ;
   __realloc_hook = nullptr;//old_realloc_hook ;
   long int oldSize = malloc_usable_size(ptr);
   void *result = realloc(ptr, size);
   long int updated_size = malloc_usable_size(result);
   memory_bytes_hook += (updated_size - oldSize);
   if(peak_memory_hook  < memory_bytes_hook )
        peak_memory_hook = memory_bytes_hook ;
   my_init_hook();
   return result;

}

static void
my_free_hook (void *ptr, const void *caller)
{
   const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(memory_mutex_hook);
   __malloc_hook = nullptr;// old_malloc_hook;
   __free_hook = nullptr;// old_free_hook ;
   __realloc_hook = nullptr;//old_realloc_hook ;
  /* Call recursively */
  long int oldSize = malloc_usable_size(ptr);
  free (ptr);
  memory_bytes_hook -= oldSize;
  if(peak_memory_hook  < memory_bytes_hook )
        peak_memory_hook = memory_bytes_hook ;
  my_init_hook();
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    my_init_hook();

    ... calling other libraries and do lot of operation for couple of hours...

     std::cout <<"At last: peak_memory hook: "<< peak_memory_hook << "\t" << " Bytes 
     allocated: " << memory_bytes_hook << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

At the end of program execution I am getting negative value of memory_bytes_hook .  I did put some logs at intermediate intervals. It was observed that memory_bytes_hook  value started reducing after some time and eventually went to negative. That's why It is not because of overflow.   I was wondering , What could be other reason of it going negative value. I was hoping, malloc hook would catch all the memory related calls.

Comment: Maybe missing error handling? Example: If `realloc` returns `NULL`, the old memory is still available and not removed. Are you sure the program will always call your hooks with valid pointers? How exactly did you check that no overflow occurred? Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Updated question with requested information.  Even if in case of memory leak that you have mentioned above. Numbers should not go to negative. It should be increased and after overflowing it will be negative.

Comment: not sure about valid whether program will always call with valid pointers or not. It there any way to check that ?

Comment: If code like `void *result = realloc(ptr, size);` returns `NULL`, this is not necessarily a memory leak because `ptr` is still a valid for the allocated memory. Only `ptr = realloc(ptr, size);` would create a memory leak in case of a failed `realloc`. If this happens you would get the size with `oldSize = malloc_usable_size(ptr);` and `updated_size = malloc_usable_size(result);` would be 0, so you would add `(updated_size - oldSize)`, i.e. subtract `oldSize` although the total memory allocation did not change. Only the implementation of `realloc` or `free` can detect invalid pointers.

Comment: Without a [mre] it is difficult or impossible to reproduce your problem.